# Getting a package not found when I do ./configure

Tags: apt, gnome, software-installation

I am trying to install msitools from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/msitools/0.94/. 
When I do a ./configure, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (libgsf-1) were not met:

No package 'libgsf-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables GSF_CFLAGS
and GSF_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

I believe that libgsf-1 is not installed, so when I do sudo apt-get install libgsf-1, I get the below error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libgsf-1 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libgsf-bin:i386 libgsf-bin libgsf-1-common 

E: Package 'libgsf-1' has no installation candidate
```

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try installing libgsf-1-dev instead:

```
sudo apt-get install  libgsf-1-dev
```

How did I know to do this? Ok, I totaly belived you when you said libgsf wasnt installed. and libgsf-1 just doesnt sound like a package name to me, if it were, its name would be libgsf-1-something.
 anyhow, I then searched the repos for the package:

```
$ sudo apt-cache search libgsf-1
libgsf-1-114 - Structured File Library - runtime version
libgsf-1-114-dbg - Structured File Library - debugging files (basic version)
libgsf-1-common - Structured File Library - common files
libgsf-1-dev - Structured File Library - development files
```

if you noticed, when you ran `sudo apt-get install libgsf-1-dev` you probably saw `libgsf-1-114 libgsf-1-common libgsf-1-dev` listed in the set of files installed. Do you need the dev version? IDK, I assume so.

Comment: It worked, thanks! Its giving similar error with other packages, will try to resolve them.
Can you please elaborate on the solution, I mean why does this package works instead of libgsf-1?

Comment: if you have more issues, let me know

Comment: -dev typically means it is some library along with headers useful for compiling against, such as when a configure script is looking for installed libraries and headers (and helper scripts) to create makefile references for. i.e., not just a library useful for dynamic loading by some other application.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys! I faced a similar issue (http://askubuntu.com/questions/690165/getting-a-package-not-found-exception-even-after-its-installed). Please comment there.