# Getting a package not found exception even after its installed

Tags: apt, gnome, software-installation

I am getting below error when I do a ./configure.

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gio-2.0 >= 0.23.0
                       libgcab-1.0 >= 0.1.10
                       uuid >= 1.41.3
                       libxml-2.0 >= 2.7) were not met:

No package 'libgcab-1.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables WIXL_CFLAGS
and WIXL_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Unlike my previous question ([Getting a package not found when I do ./configure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/689053/getting-a-package-not-found-when-i-do-configure)), this time the error is coming even after the module is installed.

```
sudo apt-cache search libgcab
libgcab-1.0-0 - Microsoft Cabinet file manipulation library
libgcab-dev - Microsoft Cabinet file manipulation library - development files

sudo apt-get install libgcab-1.0-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
libgcab-1.0-0:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.

sudo apt-get install libgcab-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libgcab-dev:i386 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 120 not upgraded.
```

What can be the problem causing this error?

**Edit**

```
apt-cache policy libgcab.*
N: Unable to locate package libgcab.*
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgcab.*'

grep "universe" /etc/apt/sources.list
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
```

Comment: ***120 not upgraded*** - maybe you should run a `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` first and try again afterwards?

Comment: did this, still not working :(

Comment: Output of `apt-cache policy libgcab.*`, please?

Comment: apt-cache policy libgcab.*  
N: Unable to locate package libgcab.*  
N: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libgcab.*'

Comment: What Ubuntu version do you use? Do you have the `universe` repository enabled? Show the output of `grep "universe" /etc/apt/sources.list`, please.

Comment: provided the o/p above in edit section.

Comment: You run 14.04 (Trusty), but `gcab` and its subcomponents are only available for Ubuntu versions starting in 15.04 (Vivid) and 15.10 (Wily). You should upgrade your system to 15.10 (as 15.04 will reach end-of-life in 3 months) or find an alternative for this package that is compatible with your version of Ubuntu. Reference: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=eo&keywords=gcab&searchon=names

Comment: The output of `uname -a` please

Comment: uname -a  :  `Linux ubuntu 3.19.0-25-generic #26~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 24 21:16:20 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: As @ByteCommander said, upgrade your system. =)

Comment: Upgrading my Ubuntu to 15.10 solved the issue. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

As you see, when you type **sudo apt-cache search libgcab** it will show you 3 versions. *the 1.0-0, the documentation and the dev* so if the ./configure thinks that there isn't file named that so try downloading dev version. **sudo apt-get install libgcab-dev**. You are trying to decompile an .msi file, aren't you? I had the same problem, and this method worked for me.